# Erase all elements from vector until first non-zero element C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector that will store a variable number of zero elements at its beginning. These need to be erased.

I have tried:

```
while(v.at(0) == 0)
{
    v.erase(v.begin());
}
```

But this throws out an `std::out_of_range` error.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand why the exception was thrown in the first place?

Comment: Your `while` condition should also check for non-empty.

Comment: Just using `stdf::find_if` is better anyway, but it's worth taking the time to understand _why_ the above approach fails the way it does.

Comment: @Useless Not sure, I figured that the erase statement meant that the next time the condition was evaluated, it failed due to the bound-checking of at(). Is that right?

Comment: [`at(0)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) will throw that when the vector is empty. You'd normally either use `operator[]` when you know the index in in-bounds (ie, you already checked it or otherwise know for sure), or `at` when you don't know _but are prepared to deal with the exception_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the first non-zero value and then [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) those elements:

```
auto first_non_zero = std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), [](int n){ return n != 0; });
v.erase(begin(v), first_non_zero);
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cc44a5167bef093))